# JOIN SQL Query for Improved Performance

Tags: sql, loops, join, while-loop

I am having performance issues and I just want to understand exactly what joining of SQL queries achieves, I have read some example and consider myself an avid coder however this one always baffles me, to the point that I just did the below to achieve my goal....

You'll see from below, first i get all AUXKEY from STAUX000 WHERE WEBSHOW = 'Y'

These results are then in a array which i implode with commas to use in the next query! - very bad i know , or is it...

I want to end of with, in the end all from STOCK table WHERE the AUXKEY is set to 'Y' in the STAUX000

Make sense?

```
$webshow = "SELECT AUXKEY FROM STAUX000 WHERE WEBSHOW = 'Y' ";
$wsres = odbc_exec($connectforwebshow, $webshow); 

while( $wsrow = odbc_fetch_array($wsres) ) { 
$_SESSION[showontheweb][] = $wsrow[AUXKEY];

}

$showondaweb = $_SESSION[showontheweb];
$imploded_arr = implode("', '000", $showondaweb);


$cfwsq = db_connect();

$wstquery = "SELECT NAME, NUMBER FROM STOCK ";
$wstquery .= "WHERE STOCK.LOCATION = 'LANE' AND UPPER(STOCK.NAME) LIKE UPPER('%') AND         NUMBER IN ('000"; 
$wstquery .= "$imploded_arr";
$wstquery .= "') ";

$wbstres = odbc_exec($cfwsq, $wstquery); 

while( $wbstrow = odbc_fetch_array($wbstres) ) {
$NUMBER = $wbstrow[NUMBER];
$_SESSION[allstock][NAME][] = ($wbstrow[NAME]);
$_SESSION[allstock][NUMBER][] = ($wbstrow[NUMBER]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to join the sql code so that the sql optimize it.

Something like:

```
SELECT NAME, NUMBER
FROM STOCK
WHERE STOCK.LOCATION = 'LANE' 
AND UPPER(STOCK.NAME) LIKE UPPER('%') 
AND exists  
(
    SELECT AUXKEY
    FROM STAUX000
    WHERE WEBSHOW = 'Y'  
    AND STOCK.NUMBER = STAUX000.AUXKEY
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply will never match the efficiency of a SQL join through a looping structure that issues inefficient queries - sorry. You might be able to quickly concatenate the query string, but that does not make for efficiency in the query execution.

I believe your loop equates to this (excluding the "like bit" for now):

```
SELECT
      S.NAME
    , S.NUMBER 
FROM STOCK S
INNER JOIN STAUX000 X ON S.NUMBER = X.AUXKEY
WHERE S.LOCATION = 'LANE' 
AND X.WEBSHOW = 'Y'
```

I seriously wish IN() was never invented, it is SO abused, and misunderstood. IN() is actually just an abbreviated form of ORs like this: `where number IN ('123','456','789',.....,'999...999')`

is executed as: `where (number='123' OR number='456' or number='789' ..... or number='999...999')`

For a SMALL set of values IN () is great, for a very large list it in NOT OK and it can get very slow indeed. It is not as efficient as using a join and does not scale to large volume. You have to remember that Relational databases are tuned for "relationships" in the data, and that's what the joins do - build relationships in the data. When you use other facilities such as IN () you are not hitting the RDBMS sweet spot, but slightly to the side, and it just ain't as good.

Also be very wary of things such as `AND UPPER(STOCK.NAME) LIKE UPPER('%')` this has multiple performance issues. I suggest you read this reference about "[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)". When you run a function such as UPPER on a field you can be removing the ability to reference an index and that will mean your query gets slow. LIKE is also problematic for performance.

Comment: Hi I tried this query, funnily i actually tried exactly this and no luck -
    SELECT
      S.NAME
    , S.NUMBER 
FROM STOCK S
INNER JOIN STAUX000 X ON S.NUMBER = X.AUXKEY
WHERE S.LOCATION = 'LANE' 
AND X.WEBSHOW = 'Y'

Comment: "no luck" means what exactly?

Comment: (using a sql tool) I would suggest you try without the `where clause` this will establish if the join is working or not. Then progressively add where conditions.

Comment: yeah i think why its not working is because both columns do not contain exact data , one actually has a prefix of 000 ie, the other is shorter and i need to add zeros is this possible without using LIKE? how to do  S.NUMBER = <prefix 000>X.AUXKEY

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STOCK.NUMBER, STOCK.NAME FROM STOCK JOIN STAUX000 ON STOCK.NUMBER =      '000'+STAUX000.AUXKEY
```

just used this and worked...

EDIT: Actually This is better ---

```
SELECT  STOCK.NUMBER, STOCK.NAME FROM STOCK JOIN STAUX000 ON RIGHT(STOCK.NUMBER, 7) = STAUX000.AUXKEY
```

For some reason comes back alot faster?